# OpenShift patch service port number

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

In OpenShift I'm trying to patch a service port number via OpenShift Client executable with this command but I get this error message.

```
$ oc patch svc fabric-boot-sample -p '{"spec":{"ports":{"port":8090}}}'
Error from server: cannot restore slice from map
```

The patch targets this part of the yaml service descriptor.

```
$ oc get svc/fabric-boot-sample -o yaml
...
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.30.48.46
  ports:
  - name: 8090-tcp
    port: 8090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8090
...
```

Is there some typo/syntax error in the patch command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `ports` that you are targeting is a list. So you will need to specify which element of the list you want to patch.

If you are sure there is only a single element in the list you could run:

`oc patch svc fabric-boot-sample --type=json -p '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/ports/0/port", "value":9999}]'`

Comment: This can also happen if you are updating a service with no ports specified with `ports: {}`.

Comment: Could you provide an example in yaml how you would specify which element of the list to patch?